# HANA procedure for CONDENSE and SPLIT

Tags: procedure, hana

I am trying to condense and split a string into single rows, e.g.

```
A     B C
```

into

```
A
B
C
```

So far, the below procedure works fine for CALL Z_SPLITROW('A B C'), but not if I have more whitespace between the chars. Any ideas?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Z_SPLITROW(TEXT nvarchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
  declare _items nvarchar(100) ARRAY;
  declare _text nvarchar(100);
  declare _index integer;
  _text := :TEXT;
  _index := 1;

  WHILE LOCATE(:_text,' ') > 0 DO
  _items[:_index] := SUBSTR_BEFORE(:_text,' ');
  _text := SUBSTR_AFTER(:_text,' ');
  _index := :_index + 1;
  END WHILE;
  _items[:_index] := :_text;

  rst = UNNEST(:_items) AS ("items");
  SELECT * FROM :rst;
END;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter out a flexible number of whitespace characters, you can use REPLACE_REGEXPR:

```
select 'A     B C' as orig,
        replace_regexpr ( '[[:space:]]+' 
                        IN  'A     B C'
                        WITH ' ') as repl
from dummy;


ORIG     |  REPL 
---------+-------
A     B C|  A B C
```